# Get Status value based on timesheet date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Assets table that has an audit log of when a particular status of that Asset changes Status... so look's something similar to this

```
AssetId     CapexStatus     Date
-------     -----------     -----
AM706       1               2017-02-03
AM706       0               2017-02-07
AM706       1               2017-02-10
```

I then have a timesheet table which has the AssetID and a transaction date on it.  I basically want to pull the Capex Status out of the AssetLog table based on the AssetId and the current Capex Status at the time of the transaction date.  eg. If the transaction date is 8th Feb then the Capex Status should be "0".

Timesheet table

```
TimesheetId     AssetId     TimesheetDate
-----------     -------     -------------
1               AM706       2017-02-01
2               AM706       2017-02-08
3               AM706       2017-02-12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this might do it:

```
select 
  t.*, 
  a.CapexStatus
from
  TimeSheet t
outer apply (Select top 1 * from AssetLog al
   where 
        al.AssetID = t.AssetID 
   and  al.Date < t.TimesheetDate
   order by al.Date desc) a
```

Comment: Sorry there doesnt seem to be any link with the assetId...i tried adding " and al.assetId=t.assetId" but record 1 return a null value

Comment: sorry Glen, fixed.

Comment: Hi Leon...when I run this the CapexStatus is NULL for TimesheetId = 1 it should return a CapexStatus of 1

Comment: That's what I expect given the data? On 2017-02-03 the capex status was set to "1". Prior to that, we have no info, the answer is unknown, thus null.

Comment: Actually, i think you are right.  My test data was just to test boundaries.  Under normal circumstances there would be no timesheets to enter if the Asset didnt already exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
create view vwMaxCapex
as
select top 1 capexStatus, date, AssetId from AssetsLog
order by date asc
go


select a.AssetId, a.timesheetDate, 
  (select capexstatus 
    from vwMaxCapex 
     where date<=a.timesheetDate and assetId=a.AssetId) capex
from timetable a
```